# My viewmodel data is not being bound to edittext

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I have bounded a viewmodel to an activity and that is working fine, but in another activity where I bound my viewmodel is not showing any data. Here is my viewmodel variable declaration in my activity:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <data>
        <variable name="profileViewModel"
            type="com.kreeti.gogal.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel"
            />
    </data>
   ......
   <EditText
       style="@style/convertible_edit_text"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_edit"
       android:text="@={profileViewModel.firstName}"/>
```

here is my viewmodel:

```
class ProfileViewModel constructor(
    val repository: ProfileRepository,
    private val mContext: Context
) : ViewModel() {
    var firstName: String? = null
    ....
init {
      Coroutines.main {
           try {
               repository.getProfileDetails().let {
                   firstName = it.data.first_name  // Here I am fetching the data
                }
           ....
     }
}
```

this is my activity class

```
class EditProfile : AppCompatActivity(), ResponseListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val networkConnectionInterceptor = NetworkConnectionInterceptor(this)
        val api = BaseApi.invoke(networkConnectionInterceptor, AuthorizedApi::class.java)
        val profileRepository = ProfileRepository(api)
        val factory = ProfileViewModelFactory(profileRepository, this)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)

        val binding: ActivityEditProfileBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_edit_profile)
        binding.profileViewModel = viewModel
     }
```

I cannot understand why my edittext is not getting the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using databinding in your xml it should be : `android:text="@{profileViewModel.firstName}"` instead of `android:text="@={profileViewModel.firstName}"` other than that I don't see any problem.

You also might be interested in this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0)

PS: `profileViewModel` shouldn't have any reference to `context` as it might create some bug, if you really need `context` you can use `AndroidViewModel` instead of `ViewModel` implementation. `AndroidViewModel` gives you access to ApplicationContext.

Comment: I have used the viewmodel variable in another activity in same way it was working fine

Comment: I just noticed in your `EditProfile` you didn't do `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
`

Comment: I used `binding.viewmodel` instead of that line and it works, do I require to write it in different way!

Comment: yes it's working now, without having any changes, with this syntax `android:text="@={profileViewModel.firstName}"`. I think `android:text="@{profileViewModel.firstName}"` can only recieve the attribute value from the viewmodel but doesn't set the value. Btw thanks :)